# WebControl rendercontents updated by Ajax

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I'm slightly puzzled by something happening in an asp.net application.

There's a control on the page which does an ajax request (using an UpdatePanel and a Trigger) every 5 seconds to loop around some images being displayed.

I've created a WebControl which fetches information from Twitter, and despite not being part of the UpdatePanel, RenderContents seems to be called on each AJAX call.

Is this normal behaviour, or am I missing something? And is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any of your code it will be hard to provide a definitive answer, however:

Note that the full page life cycle is executed even for an update panel call.  Basically ASP.Net generates the markup for the entire page but then only returns the portion for the update panel.  Whatever is in the load, prerender, etc events for the page and any of it's controls will be executed for every panel update.

You can check if you are doing a normal page load or an AJAX/update panel load by checking the value of `ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack`.  You could wrap code you don't want executed in a "not IsInAsyncPostBack" block.  Personally I would avoid using Update Panels and use pure AJAX calls to update the images.

Comment: thanks, AuSteve. Unfortunately, I'm working with a load of existing code (which I don't have the source to - don't ask) and adding a new control.

Comment: You could still wrap your logic inside a "not IsInAsyncPostBack" block so your code only runs on a full page load.